# wxcombobox as wxdataview editor

Tags: wxwidgets

Hope this wxwidgets question is welcome here.
Im trying to use a wxcombobox as a wxdataview editor. The code runs well but the editor is shown for less than half a second then it
vanishes.
Has anyone hacked this one succesfully?

Comment: Do you use wxWidgets 2.8 or the SVN trunk version? The `wxDataViewCtrl` implementation differs between them.

Comment: I tried with both 2.8.10 and 2.9.0 but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that the editor lost focus imediately after being shown. To counter this i had to overide the editor's onshow event without calling event.Skip()